# What is the closure of these sets?

Tags: general-topology

I am working through the problems in Topology by Munkres.  This comes from Section 17, #17 on page 101.

> Consider the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and the topology given by the basis $\mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C} = \{[a,b)\text{ such that }a \lt b, a\text{ and }b \text{ rational}\}$.  Determine the closure of the intervals $A = (0, \sqrt{2})$ and $B = (\sqrt{2}, 3)$ in these two topologies."

**Here is my answer.**

Closure of $A = (0, \sqrt{2})$ in the lower limit topology is $[0, \sqrt {2})$.  Every neighborhood around $0$ must intersect $A$, so $0$ is an element of $\overline{A}$.  Also, $[\sqrt 2, 4)$ is an open set which doesn't intersect $A$, thus $\sqrt{2}$ is not an element of $\overline{A}$.

Closure of $B = (\sqrt{2}, 3)$ in the lower limit topology is $[\sqrt{2}, 3)$.  Every neighborhood around $\sqrt{2}$ must intersect $B$, so $\sqrt{2}$ is an element of $B$-closure.  Also, $[3, 4)$ is an open set which doesn't intersect $B$, thus $3$ is not an element of $B$-closure.

Closure of $A = (0, \sqrt{2})$ in the topology generated by the basis $\mathcal{C}$ is $[0,\sqrt{2}]$. Every neighborhood around $0$ must intersect $A$, so $0$ is an element of $A$-closure. There do not exist open sets like $[\sqrt{2}, 4)$, where $\sqrt{2}$ is the lowest element in the set.  Thus, any open set containing $\sqrt{2}$ must contain an element lower than $\sqrt{2}$.  Thus $\sqrt{2}$ is an element of $A$-closure.

Closure of $B = (\sqrt{2}, 3)$ in the topology generated by the basis $\mathcal{C}$ is $[\sqrt{2}, 3)$.  Every neighborhood around $\sqrt{2}$ must intersect $B$, so $\sqrt{2}$ is an element of $B$-closure.  Also, $[3, 4)$ is an open set which doesn't intersect $B$, thus $3$ is not an element of $B$-closure.

Are these correct?  Any feedback would be most appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm doing the same question, but I do not understand how you can say that $[\sqrt(2),4)$ is open in this basis since a and b must be rational?

Comment: @PGibbon, that's a fair question! The OP isn't saying that $\left[\sqrt{2},4\right)$ is open in the topology generated by the basis $\mathcal{C},$ but rather, it is open in the lower limit topology. The lower limit topology is generated instead by the basis $$\mathcal{B}=\bigl\{[a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R, a<b\bigr\}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all correct. It's worth noting, though, that you should justify (for example) why there are no *other* points in the closure of $(0,\sqrt2)$ in the lower limit topology. You've demonstrated why $\sqrt2$ isn't in the closure, but why isn't there any element greater than $\sqrt2$? Why isn't there any negative element?